# What is a hyperjump?

Tags: terminology, towerfall-ascension

What is a hyperjump? How do perform one in Towerfall?

A fellow Towerfall player mentioned it, it apparently lets you jump farther than usual, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@Seiyria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221297/what-is-a-hyperjump/221302#221302) mentioned, a **SuperJump** is a way to jump far and fast using the following combination:

- Crouch (diagonal forward)
- Dodge
- Jump, which will cancel the dodge

It allows you to do a slightly better jump, retaining the speed of the dodge.

For **HyperJump**, which is different, you have to know about **Tap Canceling**.

Tap canceling is when you Dodge while already Dodge, which actually cancel the first dodge while keeping original speed. It has multiple uses, but if used but the **SuperJump** technique, can lead to **HyperJump**, so the order is:

- Crouch (diagonal forward)
- Dodge
- Dodge again (the sooner the better, but not on the same frame)
- Jump

And you'll **HyperJump**! Do note that in SuperJump and HyperJump, you can still fire arrow (which is a way to surprise your enemy) but since you just canceled your dodge, you cannot catch arrows or dash on a monster (solo mode) to avoid being hit.

It requires a lot of practice to learn how to use it properly without killing yourself, so be careful to not abuse it.

http://towerfall.wikidot.com/how-to-play will have some additional information.

Comment: "without killing yourself" How do you kill yourself with a HyperJump?

Comment: If you jump too fast you might not control the trajectory, so land into lava is possible, also if you fire upfront at the same time, you can catch up to the arrow and kill yourself.

Also you cancel your dodge, meaning that you are more opened to enemy arrows

Answer (score 7):

See [here](http://towerfall.tumblr.com/post/101753964326/hyper-jumping-primer) for some gifs.

[image: Hyperjump]

How to:

> To perform it, start by holding the analog stick diagonally forward and down to run. Next, hit the dodge button. This will start a dodge slide, which you can immediately cancel by jumping. Keep holding forward and you’ll retain your speed boost for a distance.
>   It’s important to hold the stick diagonally forward and down at the start. Holding just forward, you’ll enter a regular dodge rather than a slide. You can still jump out of a regular dodge of course, but dodge slides are faster and give you more distance.

Note:

> Keep in mind that Super Jumps are a form of dodge cancelling - this means that your dodge cooldown starts from the moment you jump. All dodge cancels leave you vulnerable, unable to catch arrows for a short time, gaining you mobility in return.